# C++ iostream cout doesnt work with "0"

Tags: c++, iostream

Look at this code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
    std::cout << "0";
    return 0;
}
```

And at this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
    std::cout << "0" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

On ideone.com 
the first 
https://ideone.com/vYTv6r
will proceed empty output, 
the second 
https://ideone.com/iAGHUr
will type "0\n".
What's the problem with iostream / gcc / my hands?
I think it's all about string with one zero, but can't explain this behaviour.

Comment: Probably a bug in ideone.

Comment: it also doesn't work when you add std::flush - I also think it's something with ideone - report that to them.

Comment: I tried std::flush, sync with stdio and some other tricks but no one fix this.
Sent a report on ideone.

Comment: Maybe string `0` gets interpreted as a number or null or something else with crazy implicit conversions in javascript used to run ideone.

Comment: [They](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3dd9e7176bbac9bd) [both](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b80b32851bc3e58) work fine on Coliru.

Comment: @VTT Umm.... very unlikely. What's more likely is poor output handling on the execution backend.

Comment: @cdhowie You get a proper output printed when you edit, press clear output button and run. It seems to be not saved or retrieved from storage later. So execution backend is fine.

Comment: @pawell streams are automatically flushed on normal program termination, so std::flush should not matter in this case

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes should but apparently they are not in case of ideone. Adding one should should flush immediately so for sure something is odd there.